# Having issues with min-height not working on textarea

Tags: html, css

I have the following in my HTML page:

[image]

and its a div containing a **label "Name"** and a **textarea below it with a height of 30vh.**

I'm having issues where I **want to keep the height of the textarea from resizing itself** whenever i adjust the **height of the browser**. Right now it is resizing when i resize the browser window height wise:

[image]

I've read up about "min-height" so I set the **min-height to 30vh** as well hoping that it would prevent the textarea from resizing height wise but its not working.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#output2 {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#name_field {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

#name_box {
    height: 30vh;
    min-height: 30vh; /*defined min-height here*/
    width: 95%;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "output2">
    <div id = "name_field">
        Name
        <textarea id = "name_box" disabled></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting value of ***min-height*** property in *"relative unit"*(in this case **vh**),set the value of min-height property in *"absolute unit"* such as **px ,mm** etc.
In this way ,you can solve this problem .Hope you understand!
Here is a correction(just focus *#name_box* selector in css):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

#output2 {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#name_field {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

#name_box {
    height: 30vh;
    min-height: 50px; /*Line to focus*/
    width: 95%;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
</style>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "output2">
    <div id = "name_field">
        Name
        <textarea id = "name_box" disabled></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```